# What's the point of using monads in an interpreter?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I recently discovered this little [scala example](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/56) called *Simple interpreter using monads*:

```
object simpleInterpreter {

  case class M[A](value: A) {
    def bind[B](k: A => M[B]): M[B] =  k(value)
    def map[B](f: A => B): M[B] =  bind(x => unitM(f(x)))
    def flatMap[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B] = bind(f)
  }

  def unitM[A](a: A): M[A] = M(a)

  def showM(m: M[Value]): String = m.value.toString();

  type Name = String

  trait Term;
  case class Var(x: Name) extends Term
  case class Con(n: int) extends Term
  case class Add(l: Term, r: Term) extends Term
  case class Lam(x: Name, body: Term) extends Term
  case class App(fun: Term, arg: Term) extends Term

  trait Value
  case object Wrong extends Value {
   override def toString() = "wrong"
  } 
  case class Num(n: int) extends Value {
    override def toString() = n.toString()
  }
  case class Fun(f: Value => M[Value]) extends Value {
    override def toString() = "<function>"
  }

  type Environment = List[Pair[Name, Value]]

  def lookup(x: Name, e: Environment): M[Value] = e match {
    case List() => unitM(Wrong)
    case Pair(y, b) :: e1 => if (x == y) unitM(b) else lookup(x, e1)
  }

  def add(a: Value, b: Value): M[Value] = Pair(a, b) match {
    case Pair(Num(m), Num(n)) => unitM(Num(m + n))
    case _ => unitM(Wrong)
  }

  def apply(a: Value, b: Value): M[Value] = a match {
    case Fun(k) => k(b)
    case _ => unitM(Wrong)
  }

  def interp(t: Term, e: Environment): M[Value] = t match {
    case Var(x) => lookup(x, e)
    case Con(n) => unitM(Num(n))
    case Add(l, r) => for (val a <- interp(l, e);
               val b <- interp(r, e);
               val c <- add(a, b))
                      yield c
    case Lam(x, t) => unitM(Fun(a => interp(t, Pair(x, a) :: e)))
    case App(f, t) => for (val a <- interp(f, e);
               val b <- interp(t, e);
               val c <- apply(a, b))
              yield c
  }

  def test(t: Term): String = 
    showM(interp(t, List()))

  val term0 = App(Lam("x", Add(Var("x"), Var("x"))), Add(Con(10), Con(11)))
  val term1 = App(Con(1), Con(2))

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(test(term0))
    println(test(term1))
  }
}
```

What's the use/advantage of monadic computations here? In fact, the `M` is nothing but an identity monad. Is this just introduced to give an example of monadic syntax or does it have an important effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a little summary of Phil Wadler's paper:
When you write an interpreter in straightforward, "direct" style, a lot of code has to change when you add a new feature.  For example, if you add exceptions, you have to check if an exception is raised any place you might evaluate an expression, even if the construct is like **if** or **while** or function call, and so has nothing to do with exceptions.

If you write the interpreter in monadic style, you can add a new feature just by changing the monad.  You usually also add a few new bits of syntax to support the feature, but none of the rest of the code changes.  So monadic style is a way of making an interpreter that is modular with respect to language changes.

Examples:

- To add exceptions, change the monad to the error monad, add new syntax and code for `throw` and `catch`, and none of your other code changes.
- To change the language so that the value of an expression is a *probability distribution*, not just a value, change the monad, and add a probabilistic construct like "flip a biased coin".  Again, none of the old code changes.  (This one is really fun; I've [done it myself](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/pmonad.pdf).)

Now that I've told you what the advantage of monadic computations, I'd better tell you the supreme disadvantage: **you can only do one interesting feature at a time**.  The reason is that in general, you cannot compose two monads to make a new monad.  This is true not just in general, but of monads you might really like to use.

If you're really interested in making a modular interpreter, in which you can easily experiment with different *combinations* of language features (as opposed to just individual features), you need **monad transformers**.  There's a great paper on [*Monad Transformers and Modular Interpreters*](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/modinterp.html) by Sheng Liang, Paul Hudak, and Mark Jones.  It's a great read; I recommend it highly.

Answer (score 4):

Using a monad makes the parser/interpreter extensible. [This paper by Philip Wadler](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) takes some time to read, but explores this idea in great detail. See also [Monadic Parsing in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/pearl.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the links. But could you please be more specific and sum up what kind of extensibility is granted by monads? Replacing identity bind by e.g. a debug output? What practical use is there for parsers. Btw: The code above has nothing to do with monadic parser combinators (as shown in your Haskell example).

Comment: Did you read the Wadler paper? He gives many different examples, logging being one of them. I know you're not parsing, but the Wadler example is interpreting, which is, I believe, what you're doing.