# What programming task provided your breakthrough with monads?

Tags: haskell, monads

In a recent blog post about a probability monad he'd written, Mark Dominus wrote, ["So I feel like I've finally arrived, monadwise."](http://blog.plover.com/prog/haskell/probmonad.html)

[My first monadic program](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2007/02/my-first-monadic-program.html) was an awkward solution to [Problem 32](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=32) from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) using [parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) and the [Maybe monad](http://www.haskell.org/all_about_monads/html/maybemonad.html).

What were you working on when the light finally turned on for you? Provide at least a sketch of the code you wrote. Knowing what you know now, how would you improve it and why?

Comment: Actually, although they had been explained to me before, I only felt I understood monads (in practice) recently after reading the post you refer to and this other one: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html . I have not used any yet, but that may be because I didn't write my first Haskell program yet.

Comment: I've not had it yet. I'm still trying to find something to write where Monads would be useful.

Comment: I second http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html. Reading that gave me the "CLICK, I've got it" feeling when I was struggling with monads.

Answer (score 4):

When I realized that I could use monad for both parsing and [interpreting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969254/whats-the-point-of-using-monads-in-an-interpreter), I was able to write my first mini-interpreter for a LUA-like dynamic programming language in F# on the first try. First-class continuations!, environment, mutable state, debugging - All just a big monad transformer stack.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a totally kosher answer to your question, because it's not really a programming task, but [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) walks from Functors to Applicatives to Monads in a really clear way that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Some random computation code base on sampling.
The type « m a » is a random variable of type « a »
and « a -> m b » is a "random function".
Random variables can very simply be handled this way.
« replicateM n » is used to get independant samples from a same variable.

The do notation is fine as well :
x <- y
means x is a sample from the random variable y.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. After a few months of not trying to understand monads and doing other things instead, the next time I thought about monads I noticed that I understood them. (This tends to happen in other areas.)

For the record, the most helpful thing was thinking in terms of join rather than (>>=), and realizing that join (:: m (m a) -> m a) is basically saying "instead of a computation A which I can run to produce a computation B (which I can run to get a value of type a), give me a new computation C which runs both A *and then* the resulting B in one step", so it's very much like the 'run' function of whichever Monad you're using, just one level up. With fmap you can produce computations of type m (m (m (m (m (m a))))), with join you can flatten them back down, and together you can create arbitrary sequencings of computations (and 'return' is the trivial computation). Sequentiality is the essence which Monad captures.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was creating a variation on the QuickCheck "Gen" monad (which is used to create random values).  I wanted to test something stateful, so I rewrote "Gen" as a monad transformer and stacked it up with a State monad.  Somewhere in there the lightbulb went on.